# PHPMailer: IsHTML is true, but fails

Tags: phpmailer

I have this code:

$mail->Host = gethostbyname('tls://'.$dados[1]->US_ENVIO_SMTP);

```
    $mail->Port = $dados[1]->US_ENVIO_PORTA;
    $mail->Username = $dados[1]->US_ENVIO_EMAIL;
    $mail->Password = $dados[1]->US_ENVIO_SENHA; 
    $mail->SetFrom($dados[1]->US_ENVIO_EMAIL, $dados[1]->US_NOME); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($dados[1]->US_ENVIO_EMAIL, $dados[1]->US_NOME); 
    $mail->Subject = $this->input->post('EM_ASSUNTO'); //Assunto do e-mail.
    $mail->Body = $css.$this->input->post("EM_DESCRICAO")."<br>".$this->input->post("EM_CONTEUDO");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
```

What I'm doing in $mail-> Body is set CSS and HTML.

**The problem:**

Gmail is receiving all code like this:

```
    <!--[if IE]><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie-browser" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><![endif]--><!--[if !IE]><!--><!--<![endif]--> <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> 96 </xml><![endif]--> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif]--> <title>E-mail template 1</title> <style type="text/css" id="media-query"> body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } table, tr, td { vertical-align: top; border-collapse: collapse; } .ie-browser table, .mso-container table { table-layout: fixed; } * { line-height: inherit; } a[x-apple-data-detectors=true] { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; } [owa] .img-container div, [owa] .img-container button { display: block !important; } [owa] .fullwidth button { width: 100% !important; } .ie-browser .col, [owa] .block-grid .col { display: table-cell; float: none !important; vertical-align: top; } .ie-browser .num12, .ie-browser .block-grid, [owa] .num12, [owa] .block-grid { width: 500px !important; } .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; } .ie-browser .mixed-two-up .num4, [owa] .mixed-two-up .num4 { width: 164px !important; } .ie-browser .mixed-two-up .num8, [owa] .mixed-two-up .num8 { width: 328px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.two-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.two-up .col { width: 250px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.three-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.three-up .col { width: 166px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.four-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.four-up .col { width: 125px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.five-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.five-up .col { width: 100px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.six-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.six-up .col { width: 83px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.seven-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.seven-up .col { width: 71px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.eight-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.eight-up .col { width: 62px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.nine-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.nine-up .col { width: 55px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.ten-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.ten-up .col { width: 50px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.eleven-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.eleven-up .col { width: 45px !important; } .ie-browser .block-grid.twelve-up .col, [owa] .block-grid.twelve-up .col { width: 41px !important; } @media only screen and (min-width: 520px) { .block-grid { width: 500px !important; } .block-grid .col { display: table-cell; Float: none !important; vertical-align: top; } .block-grid .col.num12 { width: 500px !important; } .block-grid.mixed-two-up .col.num4 { width: 164px !important; } .block-grid.mixed-two-up .col.num8 { width: 328px !important; } .block-grid.two-up .col { width: 250px !important; } .block-grid.three-up .col { width: 166px !important; } .block-grid.four-up .col { width: 125px !important; } .block-grid.five-up .col { width: 100px !important; } .block-grid.six-up .col { width: 83px !important; } .block-grid.seven-up .col { width: 71px !important; } .block-grid.eight-up .col { width: 62px !important; } .block-grid.nine-up .col { width: 55px !important; } .block-grid.ten-up .col { width: 50px !important; } .block-grid.eleven-up .col { width: 45px !important; } .block-grid.twelve-up .col { width: 41px !important; } } @media (max-width: 520px) { .block-grid, .col { min-width: 320px !important; max-width: 100% !important; } .block-grid { width: calc(100% - 40px) !important; } .col { width: 100% !important; } .col > div { margin: 0 auto; } img.fullwidth { max-width: 100% !important; } } </style> <!--[if mso]> <body class="mso-container" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"> <![endif]--> <!--[if !mso]><!--> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<![endif]--> <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>   <![endif]-->
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
<![endif]--> Image <!--[if mso]>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>    <![endif]-->
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<!--<![endif]--> <!--[if mso]>
<![endif]-->
(51) 9991-2580
<!--[if mso]>
<![endif]--> <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<![endif]--> <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>   <![endif]-->
<!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->   <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
```

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: So that must be what you’re putting in `Body`. Your code doesn’t show anything different.

Comment: @Synchro the code is way longer, this is part of it, there's css, html with images, the funny thing is HTML in some parts work's. 30 days ago, same code used to work.

Comment: Other than in the `msgHtml` function, PHPMailer does not touch your message body. What you put into `Body` is what gets sent, so check what you’re putting in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was getting body with:

```
$body = $this->input->post('html_field');
```

That can be fixed by using:

```
$body = $_POST['html_field'];
```

If you use Codeigniter or similar, that can also help you.